# Dealing with a temperature program

Tags: c++, error-handling, runtime-error

I'm studying C++ by two months using the book : Programming principles and practice using C++. At the end of the error-handling chapter I have to write a program that convert degrees from Celsius to Fahrenheit and from Fahrenheit to Celsius, the program is really simple but my problem is with the error-handling.
This is my code (I use a special library written for the book's readers) :

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

// convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit and from Fahrenheit to Celsius
int main()
    try{
        cout << "Please enter a double value representing a temperature : \n"; 

        double val = 0; 
        cin >> val; 

        if (cin) {
            double df = 9.0 / 5.0 * val + 32; // convert val to a Fahrenheit temperature
            double dc = (val - 32) / 1.8; // convert val to a Celsius temperature

            cout << "Celsius to Fahrenheit : " << df << '\n'; 
            cout << "Fahrenheit to Celsius : " << dc << '\n'; 

        }
        else error("Couldn't read the value"); // if the last input operation fails 

    }
    catch (runtime_error& e) {
        cerr << "runtime error : " << e.what() << '\n'; 
        return 1; 
    }
    catch (...) {
        cerr << "Oops, something went wrong somewhere\n"; 
        return 2; 
    }
```

Here in my program I can just deal (in a very simple way) with an erroneous input value, but I can't deal with a possibile error caused by value too large to fit a double. I thought I could use numeric_limits, but I can just use features that the author has shown me. How would you solve this problem ? Would you allow the user to enter just "plausible" value for a temperature ? Or would you report an error if a value representing a temperature is too high or too low (like 1500 Celsius degrees) Thank you for your help ;)

Comment: Totally nonrelevant, but please indent your code properly.

Comment: Right now the first problem is no `{` and `}` to open and close `main()`.

Comment: @WhozCraig I was going to say that, but the way he's written it, that might actually compile fine.

Comment: I am definitely nitpicking, but I suggest changing `32` to `32.0`, and either using `1.8` everywhere, or replacing the `/ 1.8` with `* 5.0 / 9.0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the highest (and lowest) reasonable (and maybe even physically possible - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_hot) temperatures are well within the bounds of a double, I would think that applying some more reasonable limit (which could be based on the physically possible temperatures or could be even narrower based on the specific application) would be the right approach.

Someone who enters a value outside that range has likely either made a mistake or is up to no good.  The latter you want to stop, but the former you want to help by making sure whatever values you accept are "reasonable".

Answer (score 3):

If you want limit numbers by double's capacity, then just check `std::cin.good()`. It returns `true` when everything is ok, and `false` when something is wrong (number too large to fit a double, inserted a letter instead of number, etc.).